# listview Selected Item

Tags: c#

I am using C#. I need to know how can I access data which is on listview.
thank u.

Comment: Please specify which Framework you are using. C# is a programming language not a GUI framework.

Comment: @Simon: In C#, the ListView is either a Windows Forms or WPF control. By default, assuming WinForms and not taking into account any other Framework than the .NET Framework itself is rather a good deduction. At worst, throw in your answer telling you're assuming a technology, and the asker will take what best suits his need.

Answer (score 1):

Know that Google is your best friend! ;)

Here are the [ListView Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members.aspx). You want to use the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) property.

I'm assuming Windows Forms here.

Otherwise in WPF, you have both:

[SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx), inherited from the [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) class.
[SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx), inherited from the [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) control.

Comment: Instead of writing nearly the same thing, you should have upvoted the earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedItems` property. This is a collection with all currently selected items. It may empty if no item is selected.

P.S: See the [MSDN-Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = YuorListViewName.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Items property as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx)

Comment: I don't think the Items property will return the selected item, but rather the complete ListViewItemCollection itself.

Comment: He never said that he wanted to access the selected item, just access the data which is on a list view, at least that is how I understood the question.

Comment: Yes. He says it in the title. :)

Comment: Another epic fail on my part XD